# How to use assume role credential in dynamodb (aws-sdk javascript)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, credentials, multi-factor-authentication

I already have aws assume role credentials in .aws/credetials file.
how to use it to creat sts or dynamodb like:

```
const { DynamoDB } = require('aws-sdk');
const { DocumentClient } = DynamoDB;

 const dynamo = new DynamoDB({
 endpoint: process.env.AWS_ENDPOINT,
 region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
 accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
 secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
 secretToken: process.env.aws_security_token
 });
```

I mean I got error as:

```
root@myubuntu:~/work/contacts_api# node ./seed/runner.js
```

```

> > Checking if 'contacts' table exists
> >     { UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.
> >         at Request.extractError (/root/work/contacts_api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
> >         at Request.callListeners (/root/work/contacts_api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
> >         at Request.emit (/root/work/contacts_api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
> >         at Request.emit (/root/work/contacts_api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
> >         at Request.transition (/root/work/contacts_api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
> >         at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/root/work/contacts_api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
> >         at /root/work/contacts_api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
> >         at Request. (/root/work/contacts_api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
> >         at Request. (/root/work/contacts_api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
> >         at Request.callListeners (/root/work/contacts_api/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
> >       message: 'The security token included in the request is invalid.',
> >       code: 'UnrecognizedClientException',
> >       time: 2019-01-07T05:39:54.907Z,
> >       requestId: 'A5CFV62P0TGHJH7VDIBSL0JRC3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
> >       statusCode: 400,
> >       retryable: false,
> >       retryDelay: 5.013458338738063 }

```

I want to know the correct way to initial credetials, if I want to use mfa credetials.

Comment: You're pulling in DynamoDB and DynamoDB.DocumentClient, but then create a new DynamoDB object, leaving the DocumentClient hanging off.  Maybe an oversight in the question?  They're built the same way regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the error here should give you a clue:

```
"The security token included in the request is invalid"
```

Did you try printing out the environment value

> env | grep aws_security_token

If it's empty you'll have to set the value prior to running your code.

Also, I've noticed that your other **aws** keys are all caps whereas your **aws_security_token** is all lowercase.

Comment: I tend to agree in some ways, when in doubt print it out!  Tho maybe a good debugger would be better.  I suspect that either your env vars are undefined, or `secretToken` isn't a "thing", I suspect it should be `sessionToken`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `secretToken` isn't a thing.  Here are two examples of how it could be done (how I've done it before).

That said I would encourage the construction and use of a `Credentials` where ever possible (the second example), but if you wanted to do it inline- that should work too.

```js
/** assume a role and build a DocumentClient object to make a single scan **/
;(async () => {
  const sts = new AWS.STS()
  const assumeRole = await sts
    .assumeRole({
      RoleArn: process.env.ROLE_ARN,
      RoleSessionName: process.env.ROLE_SESSION_NAME,
    })
    .promise()

  const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    region: process.env.REGION,
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: assumeRole.Credentials?.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: assumeRole.Credentials?.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: assumeRole.Credentials?.SessionToken,
    },
  })

  const scan = await dynamodb
    .scan({
      TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
    })
    .promise()

  console.log(scan)
})()
```

```js
/** 
* assume a role and build a Credentials object and use it 
* to build a DocumentClient object to make a single scan 
**/
;(async () => {
  const sts = new AWS.STS()
  const assumeRole = await sts
    .assumeRole({
      RoleArn: process.env.ROLE_ARN,
      RoleSessionName: process.env.ROLE_SESSION_NAME,
    })
    .promise()

  const credentials = new AWS.Credentials({
    accessKeyId: assumeRole.Credentials?.AccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: assumeRole.Credentials?.SecretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: assumeRole.Credentials?.SessionToken,
  })

  const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    region: process.env.REGION,
    credentials: credentials,
  })

  const scan = await dynamodb
    .scan({
      TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
    })
    .promise()

  console.log(scan)
})()
```