# How to allow a Tenant lambda function to query a dynamo table in Control Tower ROOT using NodeJs SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, multi-tenant

I have a `Lambda Function` running in a Tenant account that needs to query a `DynamoDb Table B` inside the Tenant and then query a `DynamoDb Table A` inside ROOT.
This is the code I have so far:

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddbDc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()


module.exports.testDynamo = async event => {
  try {
    let result 
    let params = {}
    
    // Query Table B inside tenant
    params = {
      TableName: 'Table_B',
      Key: { externalKey : 'CA6E03C' }
    }
    result = await ddbDc.get(params).promise()
    console.log(' result - ', result)  

    // Query Table A inside ROOT
    // Restart ddbDc CLIENT with ROOT credentials ?
    params = {
      TableName: 'Table_A',
      Key: { externalKey : 'MAP_CA6E03C' }
    }
    result = await ddbDc.get(params).promise()
    console.log(' result - ', result)



    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(
        {
          response: response,
        },
        null,
        2
      ),
    }
        
  } catch (error) {
      console.error(' testDynamo - error.stack:', error.stack)
      return {
        statusCode: 400,
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(error.stack)
      }
  } 
}
```

I think I need to `Restart ddbDc CLIENT with ROOT credentials` in order to get this access to the ROOT resources.

How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use STS AssumeRole and assume the role which you need to access that specific item/table.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddbDc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
const sts = new AWS.STS()


module.exports.testDynamo = async event => {
  try {
    let result 
    let params = {}
    
    // Query Table B inside tenant
    params = {
      TableName: 'Table_B',
      Key: { externalKey : 'CA6E03C' }
    }
    result = await ddbDc.get(params).promise()
    console.log(' result - ', result)  

    // Query Table A inside ROOT
    // Restart ddbDc CLIENT with ROOT credentials ?
    // https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/isolating-saas-tenants-with-dynamically-generated-iam-policies/
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html

    const assumeRole = await sts
    .assumeRole({
      RoleArn: process.env.ROLE_ARN,
      RoleSessionName: process.env.ROLE_SESSION_NAME,
    })
    .promise()

    const credentials = new AWS.Credentials({
      accessKeyId: assumeRole.Credentials?.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: assumeRole.Credentials?.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: assumeRole.Credentials?.SessionToken,
    })

    const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
      region: process.env.REGION,
      credentials: credentials,
    })

    params = {
      TableName: 'Table_A',
      Key: { externalKey : 'MAP_CA6E03C' }
    }
    result = await dynamodb.get(params).promise()
    console.log(' result - ', result)

    // TODO merge table data

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(
        {
          response: response,
        },
        null,
        2
      ),
    }
        
  } catch (error) {
      console.error(' testDynamo - error.stack:', error.stack)
      return {
        statusCode: 400,
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(error.stack)
      }
  } 
}
```

Comment: once I assumed the role how do I set the dynamo connection to this new role?

Comment: I think I found. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069377/how-to-use-assume-role-credential-in-dynamodb-aws-sdk-javascript . If that is the case please post the complete answer to the community.

Comment: You're welcome. Complete answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Using `Lambda function` and `Serverless Framework` do this:

`npm install --save-dev serverless-iam-roles-per-function` to install serverless-iam-roles-per-function. [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-iam-roles-per-function)

```
...
plugins:
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function
...

functions:
  listComponentsRootDynamo:
    ...
    ...
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
        Resource: "arn:aws:iam::RootID:role/roleName"
```

It will grant access to this lambda function `listComponentsRootDynamo` the access to Root-DynamoDb Table inside the Control Tower ROOT account.

Note that the role that provide that access to the Dynamo specific tables must exist in the `ROOT-IAM Roles`. Just copy its `Role ARN` in the `Resource:` portion of `iamRoleStatements:`.

Here is an example of the Role inside `Root` that provides that access to a specific Dynamo Table `<DynamoDb-Table-Name>`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:Root-Id:table/<DynamoDb-Table-Name>",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:Root-Id:table/<DynamoDb-Table-Name>/index/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

And Following the Lee Hannigan answer do this inside the `Lambda` that will query the `Root - DynamoDb Table`:

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddbDc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
const sts = new AWS.STS()


module.exports.testDynamo = async event => {
  try {
    let result 
    let params = {}
    
    // Query Table B inside tenant
    params = {
      TableName: 'Table_B',
      Key: { externalKey : 'CA6E03C' }
    }
    result = await ddbDc.get(params).promise()
    console.log(' result - ', result)  

    // Query Table A inside ROOT
    // Restart ddbDc CLIENT with ROOT credentials ?
    // https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/isolating-saas-tenants-with-dynamically-generated-iam-policies/
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html

    const assumeRole = await sts
    .assumeRole({
      RoleArn: process.env.ROLE_ARN,
      RoleSessionName: process.env.ROLE_SESSION_NAME,
    })
    .promise()

    const credentials = new AWS.Credentials({
      accessKeyId: assumeRole.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: assumeRole.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: assumeRole.Credentials.SessionToken
    })

    const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
      region: process.env.REGION,
      credentials: credentials,
    })

    params = {
      TableName: 'Table_A',
      Key: { externalKey : 'MAP_CA6E03C' }
    }
    result = await dynamodb.get(params).promise()
    console.log(' result - ', result)

    // TODO merge table data

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(
        {
          response: response,
        },
        null,
        2
      ),
    }
        
  } catch (error) {
      console.error(' testDynamo - error.stack:', error.stack)
      return {
        statusCode: 400,
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(error.stack)
      }
  } 
}
```